# Callback with jQuery .get() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping, callback

I am making a function which gets the HTML of another page with url as `iurl`, using the jQuery function `.get()`.

I have this code

```
var data1, data2, data3;
var iurl = 'example.com'; //url to get data from

$.get(iurl, function(response){
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    let parsedHtml = parser.parseFromString(response, 'text/html');
    data1 = parsedHtml.getElementById('id1').value;
    data2 = parsedHtml.getElementById('id2').value;
    data3 = parsedHtml.getElementById('id3').value;

   $(".table-main").append("\<tr\>\<td\>" + data1 + "\<\/td\>\<td\>" + data2 + "\<\/td\>\<td\>" + data3 + "\<\/td\>\<\/tr\>"); //displays the data in a table

    console.log("first data1 is " + data1 + " data2 is " + data2 + " data3 is " + data3);
})

alert("something");
console.log(" second data1 is " + data1 + " data2 is " + data2 + " data3 is " + data3);
```

And, I get the output as

```
second data1 is <data1> data2 is undefined data3 is undefined
first data1 is <data1> data2 is <data2> data3 is <data3>
```

but the required output is

```
first data1 is <data1> data2 is <data2> data3 is <data3>
second data1 is <data1> data2 is <data2> data3 is <data3>
```

I know I have to use the callback here, but I am not able to figure it out in this case.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your second console.log is outside of the functions scope { } so it will just run before the response from the get function!

Comment: I get it. But how can I ensure the the second console log runs after the response?

Comment: @Sparlarva But why does scope matter in this case? I think this is because while the function is executing, the second console.log gets executed. By that time, only data1 has been retrieved, so it outputs only data1, but gives data2 and data3 as undefined. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you want to ensure that your next logic is fired until the callback is done, you can use when. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: @jtorrescr I edited my code with .when(), but I still get the same output. Code [here](https://repl.it/repls/ImmaculateCrookedFrontpage)

Comment: You can do it with a top-level await but that will probably cause more problems than it solves.